# Proof why solution of linear diophantine equation $ax-by=1$ is found by sign change of solution for $b$ in solution of $ax+by=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, diophantine-equations

Say, given LDE $113 x +42y=1$ have solution given by
$$113 = 2.42 +29\implies 29= 113 - 2.42$$
$$42= 1.29+13 \implies 13=42 -1.29$$
$$29= 2.13 +3 \implies 3=29 -2.13$$
$$13= 4.3 +1\implies 1=13 -4.3$$
$$3= 3.1 +0$$

Writing in reverse.
$$13 -4.3=1$$
$$13 -4.(29 -2.13)=1\implies -4.29 + 9.13= 1$$
$$-4.29 + 9.(42-29)=1\implies -13.29 + 9.42= 1$$
$$9.42 -13.(113-2.42)= 1\implies 
35.42-13.113= 1$$

So, one solution is $(X,Y)= (-13, 35)$.

Learned that for LDE  $113 x -42y=1$, one solution $(X,Y)= (-13, -35)$

How it is obtained is unclear.

Say, applying the same process to
LDE $113 x -42y=1$ get:

$$113 = (-2).(-42) +29\implies 29= 113 + 2.(-42)$$
$$(-42)= (-1).29+(-13) \implies -13=(-42) + 1.29$$
$$(-29)= 2.(-13) -3 \implies -3=(-29) -2.(-13)$$
$$(-13)= 4.(-3) -1\implies 1=(13)+4.(-3)$$
$$-3= -3.1 +0$$

Writing in reverse.
$$13 +4.(-3)=1$$
$$13 +4.(-29 -2.(-13))=1\implies -4.29 + 9.13= 1$$
$$-4.29 + 9.(42-29)=1\implies -13.29 + 9.42= 1$$
$$9.42 -13.(113-2.42)= 1\implies 
35.42-13.113=1$$

So, where erred in not getting
$-35.42-13.113=1$

Cannot understand if this approach is flawed of getting solution for opposite sign of $b$, i.e. need an alternative way; or erred above.

If alternative approach is the only way; say, sign change of $b$ means simply sign change of $Y$; then need a better way to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your approach is fine, but from $35\cdot 42 - 13\cdot 113 = 1$, you get
$113\cdot (-13)-42\cdot(-35)=1$ for a solution of $(-13,-35)$, the expected result.

But simpler is to observe:
$$\begin{array}{ccl}
(a,b) {\rm\;is\; a\; solution\; of\;} 113x+42y &\Rightarrow& 113a+42b=1\\
&\Rightarrow&113a-42\cdot(-b) =1 \\
&\Rightarrow& (a,-b) {\rm \;is\; a\; solution\; of\;} 113x-42y=1
\end{array}$$